# AWS S3 Error 'Policy has invalid resource'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was moving S3 bucket from source bucket to destination bucket.
below is reference to do the work.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/?nc1=h_ls

but I've got error while making policy. error message is `Policy has invalid resource`

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I had changed policy for test and It worked. difference is as follows.

`arn:aws:s3:::<SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME>` > `arn:aws:s3:::<DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME>`

I don't know why It doesn't work if I fill out my SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME.

I swear source bucket name is not wrong. you might think that question is like a fool and I also assume It'll be nothing but I couldn't find any point. Please give me a hand if you know the answer. thanks for reading :)

### + be added

bucket policy that I attached to the source bucket.
replaced principal is ARN of the IAM identity in target(destination) account.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/ws.kim"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that this is **invalid bucket policy**. Instead it should be **managed IAM policy** that you create and attach to IAM role or user.

Please check the [How can I copy S3 objects from another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/?nc1=h_ls) article again and you will be able to properly setup this policy.

Comment: thanks. I've been attached policy on S3 bucket but It was wrong. I should've attached policy on my destination account's IAM policy.